# Issue with Bouncy Castle versions

Tags: digital-signature, bouncycastle, verify

My code which signs and verifies the string works fine when using bounty castle bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar. I have upgraded the jar to bcprov-jdk15on-1.66.jar, my code starts throwing below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
    at com.esb.cms.CmsCryptographyEngine.sign(CmsCryptographyEngine.java:124)
    at com.esb.cms.CmsCryptographyEngine.main(CmsCryptographyEngine.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

The restriction is, I have to use bcprov-jdk15on-1.66.jar. How can I fix it on this version?

Comment: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/wiki/Porting-From-Earlier-BC-Releases-to-1.47-and-Later

Comment: Do you mean _Bouncy_ Castle?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, I was able to solve this issue. Code change was required from 1.46 to 1.66.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.